# Android Studio: IncorrectOperationException when 'Add as Library' is clicked whilst trying to configure Google Apps Endpoints client libraries

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am trying to generate and use the android client libraries for a Python google app engine project following this guide https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android

Everytime I get to this step

> Select the library you just added, right-click, then select Add As
>   Library to your project.

I get the following exception:

> IncorrectOperationException: Must not change document outside command
>   or undo-transparent action.

I'm new to Android Studio but can't seem to find any resources on how to get endpoints client libraries working in Eclipse. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a temporary bug in Android Studio. Instead of using the Add as Library option (which wouldn't work anyway due to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66610), instead go to **File** > **Project Structure** > **Modules** > *your module* > **Dependencies** > **+** button, **File dependency**, and select your jar from the file chooser.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same `Incorrect Operation Exception` in Android Studio version 0.5.0.

This post helped me: 
[How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

To add your endpoints client library as `library` to your project, you can manually 
add your `library` to the Gradle project, in the `settings.gradle` file:

1. Open `settings.gradle`, which should be in the root of your Android Studio project.
2. Add the directory, that contains your jar file, which you want to use as a library to the `settings.gradle` file, like so:

   include ':initial_module', ':libraries:lib1', ':libraries:lib2'

   here are `lib1` and `lib2` the names of the directories that contain the `jar` file which i want to use as a library and the `:libraries` is the directive to treat it as library.
3. Gradle needs to be synced to pick up the newly added libraries.

Comment: I didn't try this suggestion as the one I've marked as answer worked but thanks for answering.